# Looking for a PHP Indentation tool?

Tags: php, indentation

Is there something like the ["phpCodeBeautifier"](http://www.waterproof.fr/products/phpCodeBeautifier/) from waterproof that is open source?

Comment: with "open source" you mean "free"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tool I know to reformat PHP code is the [`PHP_Beautifier`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Beautifier) PEAR package, which is both free *(open source)* and free *(costs no money)*.

It's a bit complicated, has a lot of options, and is maybe a bit slow, but does really good job on messy code-source.

Comment: Add that I couldn't even make it install. This made me sad.

Answer (score 0):

Open source:

http://www.bierkandt.org/beautify/

Commercial:

http://www.sourceformat.com/php-formatter.htm

Answer (score 0):

For something quick you might want to consider

http://www.prettyprinter.de/