# Need help installing/running tidy php

Tags: php, coding-style, tidy

I have used tidy for html. From the terminal I run $ tidy -fmi /path/to/file

Doing the same for a php file doesn't 'tidy' it up. Basically I'd like to run a command and have all my code indented properly. Or not run a command at all and have the text editor automatically indent all the code properly.

The main text editors I work with are vim, gvim and gedit.

system is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Comment: Check out this previous question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932768/php-auto-indent-the-whole-code

Comment: Another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458401/looking-for-a-php-indentation-tool  there are several others, I'd search for php and indentation

Answer (score 0):

Thank @ben

```
sudo aptitude insall php-pear
```

then

```
sudo pear install PHP_Beautifier-0.1.15
```

If someone can point out a better command than

```
php_beautifier -s4 -l "ArrayNested() IndentStyles(style=bsd) NewLines(before=if:switch:while:for:foreach:function:T_CLASS:return:break,after=T_COMMENT)"
```

This command works, but it has a little less indentation than I prefer. That would be great if someone could point out a better one.